# Recuperar erros com php e enviar via mensagem

Tags: php

Eu estou fazendo uma integração do slack com minha aplicação para mostrar toda vez que acontecer algum erro no sistema chegará uma mensagem no canal do slack.

usando a API já consigo enviar mensagem através do Curl: segue o código>

```
function slack($message, $room = "unique", $icon = ":ghost:") {

$data = array(
    "username" => "slackbot",
    "channel" => "#canal",
    "text" => $message,
    "mrkdwn" => true,
    "icon_url" => $icon,
    "attachments" => array(
         array(
            "color" => "#b0c4de",
        //  "title" => $message_primary_title,
            "fallback" => "fallback",
            "text" => "attachments",
            "mrkdwn_in" => array(
                "fallback",
                "text"
            ),
            "fields" => array(
                array(
                    "title" => "fileds tittle",
                    "value" => "fields value"
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$slack_webhook_url = "minha url da api";

$slack_call = curl_init($slack_webhook_url);
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_CRLF, true);
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Content-Length: " . strlen($json_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($slack_call);
curl_close($slack_call);

 return $result;   
}
```

Agora falta formatar a mensagem para o slack com os erros. Link onde acontece o erro, linha, tipo de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, queria pegar essas variáveis que o php mostra quando acontece algum erro.

queria que funcionasse mais ou menos dessa forma que coloquei abaixo >

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = function() {
//se achar erros chama o método que envia mensagem pro slack enviando os dados

if($error){
        $message = "erro no sistema ;". $error['message'];
        $slack = slack($message, $linha, $tipo);
    }
}
```

Se alguém puder ajudar fico muito grato.

Comment: Removi as tags "javascript", "laravel", "codeigniter" e "webhooks" pois não parecem ter relação com a pergunta. Se fiz errado por favor me corrija.

Comment: é pq estou usando codeigniter e o hooks.php do framework. Acho que javascript e laravel realmente me equivoquei. vlw

Answer (score 0):

Olhando [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.exception.php) podemos facilmente ver os métodos que a classe Exception do PHP dispõe. Todas essas informações são recuperáveis via esses métodos, então, é só você formatar sua mensagem da forma que desejar! =)